# How to convert from a webmap on ArcGIS to downloading shapefile format?

Tags: shapefile, arcgis-online, web-mapping

I have a ArcGIS item in the format of a Web Map and would like to download it as a shapefile (or similar format, such as KMZ or CSV, would also be acceptable)

Is this possible, and if not, why?

By the way, here's the menu containing options that I see:

[image]

Comment: Can you post a link to the map?

Comment: It's private, should I make it publicly viewable?

Comment: @HeikkiVesanto It's private, should I make it publicly viewable?

Answer (score 1):

This will not work with a web map, only with a layer. If you're used to ESRI desktop GIS, think of the webmap as the MXD document, you can't export that to a shapefile. But you can export the layers contained within the MXD.

To do that in a webmap, you need to look for the layer names listed on the main part of the page you got the screenshot from. There will be a "Layers" heading, which lists all of the layers contained in the map. Click on the layer you want (do this for each one you want of course).

[image: screenshot of webmap item page]

This will take you to the layer's item page, where you will now see an "Export Data" option in the right-hand side menu. Here you can export to shapefile (or a variety of other formats).

[image: screenshot of layer item page]

It should also be noted that this is not available for all layers. The owner of the layer can disable this option, and some layer types don't support exporting at all.

If there is a feature layer that has exporting disabled, you can still use other tools to download the data, though. You could for example use the free Python package [Bolton & Menk ArcGIS REST API](https://github.com/Bolton-and-Menk-GIS/restapi) to download the data from the service.

*I am the maintainer of the above mentioned Python package. There are probably alternatives available as well.*

Comment: As I mentioned in the text box above, this option did not appear for me, as there was no subtitle with the heading under "Layers". How can I access this anyway, instead? Thank you very much for the comment.

Comment: @Anna Can you take a look at my edits and let me know if that helps?

Comment: How can I use the application at your link? Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Are you the owner of the web map and data layers in the map?

I haven't ever seen an option to download a whole web map that actually works without the owner packaging the map. Usually, you'd open ArcGIS Pro and login to ArcGIS Online through there. If the web map you're trying to view locally is shared you can find it by opening the Catalog pane, clicking Portal, and searching for the web map's name.

Another option if you are the owner of ArcGIS Online content: back in AGOL web map, you can click the layer's "more options" ellipsis -> show item details. This opens up a new window in your web browser displaying the layer's content page. There will be an option to "Export Data" on the right where you can choose to download in shp/KMZ/CSV formats.

If you aren't the owner, then contact the owner and ask if they can enable others to export data. This is a checkbox option under the layer's settings.

Comment: Thank you. Like I said in the original question, yes I am. From tutorials I've seen there is no such option through AG Desktop either, but I'll try in AGOL if you can show/find for me where that option is on the web map's page, perhaps?

Comment: that's exactly what my image from the bar on top shows. There's no button where that appears as an option, so could getting it on ArcGis Desktop somehow help?